# How can you have multiple instances of a class run a method in parallel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So essentially I have a class defined as follows

```
class SensorGrouping:
  def __init__(self, address, screen_identifier):
      self.factory = PiGPIOFactory(host=address)
      self.group_id = screen_identifier
      self.ir_sensor_vertical = MotionSensor(MOTION_PIN_VERTICAL, pin_factory=self.factory)
      self.led = LED(LED_PIN, pin_factory=self.factory)

  def wait_for_detection():
      self.ir_sensor_vertical.wait_for_motion()
      return self.group_id
```

The intention is to have multiple of the SensorGrouping classes. wait_for_motion() will sit idle until the sensor is activated. What I will want to do is wait for one of their IR sensors to be triggered, and then return the group_id of the SensorGrouping which was triggered first, killing the others in the process. I've looked into multiprocessing's imap function but it doesn't seem to fulfill what I want. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: You could try something like this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: @mousetail I had looked into it but there doesn't seem to be a way to force a thread to terminate, and the wait_for_motion() method will not return until the motion sensor it is monitoring is activated, and it would not be useful to wait for it when it may never detect something.

Comment: The trick for terminating a thread is to do something to the thing its waiting on. For instance, if you can close `self.ir_sensor_vertical` it would likely return to the thread.

Comment: Its common for waitable things to have an async option. Maybe a socket that can be put in `select()` or a lock or mutex or something. Alternately, it may wire into an async framework like python's asyncio.